# How to add wiris to django-ckeditor

Tags: python, django, plugins, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I want to use CKEditor+WIRIS plugin in my Django-based project.
I successfully installed django-ckeditor. But I dont know which WIRIS plugin should be used. In [download page](http://www.wiris.com/en/plugins3/ckeditor/download), there are some plugins for php, Java, ASP and...
But there is not any plugin for Django or python.
Can I use one of these plugins to add it to django-ckeditor? which one and how?

Comment: We have recently released our plugin for Ruby on Rails. Unfortunately, Phyton or Django are not on our roadmap. We typically do new technology plugin developments depending on our client requests (or the projects they are involved). We haven't had many clients requesting Phyton. In any case, please feel free to contact us at sales@wiris.com so you can discuss this further.

Answer (score 0):

Download it from [HERE](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/ckeditorwiris) then extract it in path bellow

```
<BASE_DIR>/static/ckeditor/plugins/
```

then you can add it to your plagins :

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'toolbar': 'full',
        # ...
    'extraPlugins': ','.join([
        # ...
        'ckeditor_wiris',
        # ...
    ]),

}}
```